# How to correctly unpickle with Python 2.7 what has been pickled using 2.5?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, pickle, python-2.5

I am migrating a web app from Python 2.5 runtime to Python 2.7.
My app stores pickled data into the database, and when unpickling what I stored I have some issues with long integers:

An int like 100003087328067, pickled using Python 2.5, gets unpickled to 2147483647 (which is 2^31-1) under Python 2.7.

How to retrieve the right value?

Can there be other issues? With str encoding for instance?
(I found this but it's with python 3: [Unpicking data pickled in Python 2.5, in Python 3.1 then uncompressing with zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281619/unpicking-data-pickled-in-python-2-5-in-python-3-1-then-uncompressing-with-zlib))

*More about my context:
I am migrating a Google App Engine app, and I stored my data using a custom db.Property that acts a bit like the NDB PickleProperty.*

Comment: by the way, is this a pickle issue? I can read in the docs: `The pickle serialization format is guaranteed to be backwards compatible across Python releases` [(here)](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Agreed it sounds fishy. Probably the Python 2.7 is built with 32-bit ints while the 2.5 is built with 64-bit ints. Did you get this result in production or using the dev appserver?

Comment: Not that I can reproduce this or necessarily believe it is a bug in pickle -- could you show an example pickle that has this value (using the repr() function) and the code you use to unpickle it?

Comment: I got it in production. I'm using this [SerializableProperty](http://thesweeheng.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/gae-storing-serializable-objects-in-datastore/) for storage. What I pickle is a dict of dict, each nested dict values are either unicode, bool, datetime, long, int or list of unicode. I'm looking for pickled data to give you

Comment: As I tried so simplify I realized that just using the memcache API is enough to reproduce. I have deployed a version that adds `{'k1': {'v1': True, 'v2': 100003087328068}}` to memcache using Python25, and can read it using another url. Then another version with the same code but using Python27. After adding with p25, reading with p25 gets it right while reading with p27 returns `{'k1': {'v1': True, 'v2': 2147483647}}`

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce this, and it surely looks like a bug in the Py27 runtime. I'll raise this internally.

Comment: Good news. Our Python 2.7 engineering team has tracked down the bug and a fix is on the way, slated for inclusion in the 1.6.3 runtime to be released later this month.  Thanks @Alexis for reporting this and for providing me with a reproducible test case!

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a two stage setup:

Write a Python 2.5 script to unpickle the current values, store them with a common format like JSON, then read it back into a Python 2.7 app.

Ideally, continue to use a format like JSON rather than pickling, so that it isn't dependant on the platform in the future. Even better, store the data in the database as properly normalised data, so it can be used even more easily.

Comment: Indeed we plan to use JSON more extensively, and there are only a few places where we have non-json-like data stored. So it may be the opportunity to make that change sooner...